# how to insert image in sqlite3 through command prompt

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I am new to Ionic framework. I created table in sqlite3 with column type is Blob. I followed this tutorial.
http://johnatten.com/2014/12/07/installing-and-using-sqlite-on-windows/#Open-a-New-Database-and-Create-Some-Tables-from-the-SQLite3-Console

But how to insert image through command prompt.
please help me.